# Error trying to get YouTube access token from a user {error: "unsupported_grant_type", error_description: "Invalid grant_type: "}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth-2.0, youtube

I'm actually using a ruby gem ("yt") to get the permission from a user to access his youtube account. So far so good, as indicated here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps?hl=es i get to the step 3 with no problems and get the code which is something like 4/adsfaisdofjaosifjosdifjsdoajifsado (you get the idea, lots of random characters).

The documentation then says i need to make a POST request like the following to use that code to get the actual access token:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&
client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&
redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

So i do. I tried it both with curl -d in the console and using fetch with javascript passing all the asked info. My javascript code looks like this:

```
 fetch("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Host': 'accounts.google.com',
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    body: {
                "code": '4/2asdasdasdasd',
                "client_id": 'myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                "client_secret": 'myclientsecret',
                "grant_type": "authorization_code",
                "redirect_uri": 'https://myuri'
              }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

What i get is a POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token 400 error and the JSON returned is this:

```
{error: "unsupported_grant_type", error_description: "Invalid grant_type: "}
```

does anyone have any idea of what's going on?